# Intervention/Image requires FileInfo

Tags: php, linux, apache, pecl, centos6.5

Im having trouble with Intervention/image, Laravel `#composer install`

```
- intervention/image 2.1.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP
extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
```

I understand that it is trying to retrieve the extension `fileinfo` however I am having 0 luck with getting the extension to load.

I believe that as of PHP 5.4 the extension `fileinfo` is automatically enabled, however it isnt showing up in `#php -m` modules.

`#pecl install fileinfo` doesnt work either because my php version doesnt suit any versions of `fileinfo`.

**My PHP version is:**

```
PHP 5.4.37 (cli)
```

**Operating System:**

```
Linux
CentOS 6.5 cPanel 11.46 / Softaculous x64
```

---

Ive tried adding

```
extension = "fileinfo.so"
```

to the *php.ini* however to no luck, it does nothing.

**NOTE:** I managed to get the extension for windows version of php 5.4 working... Its just when I have uploaded my website to my server, I have been unable to get it to load, well get that library (*Intervention/Image*) to load.

---

Other details:

- Server is a **VPS** with access to **WHM** and **cPanel**
- Website works. Everything except the Intervention/Image

Answer (score 2):

go to 'Select PHP version ' under Software section in your cPanel. Then check fileinfo checkbox.  Then save. That's it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you just have to enable your fileinfo from your php configuration.

To do so :

1. Go to php.ini in your php install folder ( for me since I used bitnami on windows, it is located at C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.6.31-0\php )
2. Uncomment the line ;extension=php_fileinfo.dll by removing the semicolon. ( on linux you should have extension=php_fileinfo.so )
3. Restart php ( use the command line on unix, or on windows through the manager of the soft you use, for instance if you have bitnami it's in C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.6.31-0 and the exe you have to use is manager-windows.exe then click on php and restart ).

This is it.