# PHP fileinfo extension

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I uncommented

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

in both php.ini's (production and development), but still can't install package using composer. 
When I run `php -m` , I can't see fileinfo module. I'm using xampp.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Did you restart your webserver (i. e. Apache)? The module should be loaded after the restart.

Comment: @codedge Yes, I did. And I'm still not seeing it when type `  php -m `

Comment: there is also a different php.ini for CLI and web server. Did you enable the extension in your php.ini for CLI as well?

Comment: I have INI-PRODUCTION and INI-DEVELOPMENT files. And I uncomment fileinfo in both of them.

Comment: As I said, there is a php configuration for command line (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) - which is used when you run 'php -m'. Please check that you enabled the module there as well. Otherwise you wont see the change. If you want to check if your changes, that you made is successful, create a script with 'echo phpinfo();' and check the output.

Comment: Just by chance - same issue as here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507943/intervention-image-requires-fileinfo

Comment: Yes, the same. Except  I have this problem on my local machine with XAMPP. On other pc there is no issue, and I've done everything the same.

Answer (score 2):

Found solution to this in MAMP.

PHP 7.1.5 is used as an example, but you likely are using a different version.

In addition to editing the php.ini in `mamp\bin\php7.1.5\php.ini`, you need to add `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` in `mamp\conf\php7.1.5\php.ini`. Notice the **conf** folder.

In configurations, the file doesn't seem to be related to the running server, but it does in fact make a difference.